# How do I enforce a UTF8 encoding on a generated CSV report?

Tags: python, web2py

How do I enforce a UTF8 encoding on a generated CSV report in web2py?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `str.encode` function together with the csv module, there is a complete example that will show you that [in the Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#module-csv) (or in the link given in comment to your question). Quick example:

```
row = ["one", "two", "three"]

import csv
with open("report.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow([s.encode("utf-8") for s in row])
```